# Match multiple patterns in strings

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, filter

Is the first time that I am using Pattern and Match classes and I have a problem.
I would like to output only the strings that match all the patterns but all I am getting are the lines that match separately the patterns, first the ones that passes the first filter and second the lines that contains the second filter. My code:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p;
    Matcher m;
    String f;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> fArr = new ArrayList<String>();

    arr.add("A");
    arr.add("C");
    arr.add("A B");
    arr.add("A C");
    arr.add("A C M");

    String A = ("A");
    String C = ("C");
    fArr.add(A);
    fArr.add(C);

    for (int i = 0; i < fArr.size(); i++) {
        f = fArr.get(i);
        System.out.println("\nFILTER: " + f);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            p = Pattern.compile(f);
            m = p.matcher(arr.get(j));
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(arr.get(j));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output for this is:

```
FILTER: A
A
A B
A C
A C M

FILTER: C
C
A C
A C M
```

This example is with two filters only, but I don't know if later I will have to put more.

This is the desired output

```
 A C
 A C M
```

Are there any possibilities to do this with Pattern and Match? If not, with another classes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra loop. Eliminate the other loop and try this one:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) 
{
    p = Pattern.compile("A C");
    m = p.matcher(arr.get(j));
    if (m.find()) 
    {
        System.out.println(arr.get(j));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A C
A C M
```

**Edit:** If you want the strings that contains more than one character, than you should add an `if` condition.

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) 
{
    p = Pattern.compile("C");
    if(arr.get(j).length() > 1)
    {
        m = p.matcher(arr.get(j));
        if (m.find()) 
        {
            System.out.println(arr.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. But you only want patterns that has C in it. You surely will get "C" on its own because of your `arr.add("C")` code

Answer (score 0):

Since you need all of the patterns to match, you cannot print when just one of the patterns match.

You want Pattern A AND Pattern B AND ....  By De Boole's law, this is the same than Not (Not Pattern A OR Not Pattern B).

What does that mean? Repeat the test, if one of the strings does not match a pattern, delete it from the array. In the end, print only the Strings that are kept in the array after all the matching is done.

Comment: Oh, and `Pattern.compile()` is an expensive operation, you want it done as few many times as possible (in the outer most loop, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You have your loops nested the wrong way around. Try this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
    boolean is_a_match = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < fArr.size(); i++) {
        f = fArr.get(i);
        p = Pattern.compile(f);
        m = p.matcher(arr.get(j));
        if (!m.find()) {
            is_a_match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (is_a_match) {
        System.out.println(arr.get(j));
    }
}
```

The idea is that if it gets through the inner loop without a mismatch, then it's considered a match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" (\\s+A\\s+) .* (\\s+C\\s+).*");
```

Comment: A little explanation of how this regex works might be useful to the OP.